# response.success gives me "Object #<Object> has no method 'success'" error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to setup the protocols for handling success and error in my javascript function, however it doesn't seem to be cooperating when the function is successful. I'm receiving the following error:

```
Failed with: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'success'
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:77:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:571:19)
```

Here's the full function:

```
// Sends search query to eBay

Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*App ID GOES HERE*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {


// parses results

          var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          var items = [];

          response.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.forEach(function(itemByKeywordsResponse) {
            itemByKeywordsResponse.searchResult.forEach(function(result) {
              result.item.forEach(function(item) {
                items.push(item);
              });
            });
          });


// count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), return top two


          var categoryResults = {};

          items.forEach(function(item) {
            var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
            if (categoryResults[id]) categoryResults[id]++;
            else categoryResults[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(categoryResults).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return categoryResults[b]-categoryResults[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top categories: ' + top2.join(', '));



// compare categoryResults to userCategory object

          var userCategory = ['9355']; 

          var AnyItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory = Object.keys(categoryResults).some(function(item) {
            return userCategory.indexOf(item) > -1;
          });
          console.log('Matches found: ' + AnyItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory);

          var ItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory = Object.keys(categoryResults).filter(function(item) {
            return userCategory.indexOf(item) > -1;
          });
          console.log('User categories that match search: ' + ItemsOfCategoryResultsInUserCategory);

          response.success('Victory!');


  },
          error: function (httpResponse) {
              console.log('error!!!');
              response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
          }
     });
});
```

Line 77 that it refers to is this one:

```
response.success('Victory!');
```

Comment: `response` is an object that was generated from a JSON string. json strings can't contain functions. i don't quite see why you were even attempting `response.success('Victory!')` as it makes no sense. `response.error("...")` will fail too.

Comment: I see what you mean. How would I structure it so that it properly calls success/error?

Comment: @ghobs You have 2 `response` variables being defined, with one [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)/hiding the other. You'll have to rename one of them so the other remains available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
```

You set `response` to be a json object, and as far as i can see no `response.success` function is added to the object.
I guess the `response` you want is the one passed into

```
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
```

so you need to rename one of the response objects.

Comment: This also worked for me, even though I hadn't even set a response variable. I guess just running query.get automatically creates a response variable?